# Typescript - Get a union of keys from function parameters

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

Let's suppose I have a function:

```
const myFunc = (rowIndex: number, name: string, props: any): void => { }
```

And I need to get a union of its parameters like `rowIndex | name | props`.

Thus, I created a type:

```
type FuncParams<F extends (...args: any[]) => any> = 
    F extends (...args: infer T) => any ? { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends any ? K : never }[keyof T] : never;
```

Which returns a string union represented by numeric values: `"0" | "1" | "2"`.
What should I do to get named keys?

Comment: You can't. The names of parameters are not observable by the type system.

Answer (score 0):

For that to be possible, your function should be defined as

```
function myFunc (
    {rowIndex, name, props}: {rowIndex: number, name: string, props: any}
): void {
    /* ... */
}
```

i.e. to have an object argument.

The function argument names are treated like *comments* and can't be used in code (i.e. can appear only in type hint popups)